# Immutable state not being loaded in redux-persist-immutable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, immutable.js

I'm having an issue with redux-persist-immutable not rehydrating my store, and I'm not sure why it's happening. I'm using the ["Delay Render Until Rehydration Complete" recipe](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist/blob/master/docs/recipes.md) from the base redux-persist docs. [My exact code is here.](https://github.com/grobolom/ShadowVerseWinTracker/blob/master/src/index.jsx)

It looks like my app loads properly and everything is rendered properly, but my store.getState() returns the initialState I started with - immutable's Map() - instead of any of the values I worked with in the previous session. Am I missing something? I've added the relevant code below as well.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {compose, createStore} from 'redux';
import {getStoredState, persistStore, autoRehydrate, createPersistor} from 'redux-persist-immutable';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';

import reducer from './reducer';
import WinTracker from './components/WinTracker';

// hotmodule reloading fix
if (module.hot) {
  module.hot.accept();
}

require('./normalize.css');
require('./skeleton.css');
require('./style.css');

const store = createStore(reducer, undefined, autoRehydrate());

class AppProvider extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = { rehydrated: false }
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    persistStore(store, {}, () => {
      this.setState({ rehydrated: true })
    })
  }

  render() {
    if(!this.state.rehydrated){
      return <div>Loading...</div>
    }
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <WinTracker />
      </Provider>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <AppProvider />,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Figures I'd figure out the answer mere minutes after posting the question.

Looks like the initialState needs to be set with the keys you'll be working with later. If your initialState is an empty Map() that then gets updated, you'll be SOL.